# Language-Specific Configuration: ColorColumn

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

I used `set colorcolumn=80` and set the color to red in the python.vim file. Works like a champ - even for all other files.

I'd also like to `set colorcolumn=110` for C files though; this one has been set to darkgray for color separation.

It seems the [order of loading](https://github.com/todd-dsm/vimSimple/blob/master/vim/after/loadlangs.vim) is the problem; if [`python.vim`](https://github.com/todd-dsm/vimSimple/blob/master/vim/after/langs/python.vim) loads last, its column and color are used; if `clang.vim` is loaded last, then it stomps the `python.vim`.

Turning the dial back, I've been diddling with my own tailored vim setup for quite a while now. I clearly got a little carried away with the modularity; that notwithstanding:

***Within the existing context, how would one make this change so it's language specific?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the standard way to do this is to create `autocommands` groups:

```
augroup python
    au! " clear augroup when reloading vimrc
    autocmd FileType python set colorcolumn=80
augroup END

augroup cc
    au! " clear augroup when reloading vimrc
    autocmd FileType c,cpp set colorcolumn=110
augroup END
```

is a way to execute specific commands for a given filetype.

But as you want to source specific files given a filetype, then you should use:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim
~/.vim/ftplugin/clang.vim
```

to load your personal commands.

Comment: If you do appreciate my help, you can accept my answer and vote it up ;-) otherwise you're welcome!

Comment: Accepted! I attempted to vote it up but there are restrictions for newbs; gotta get 15 rep before I can vote, sorry man.